# Render HTML definition lists in Lift

Tags: lift

Another lift beginner question:

I want to render a [HTML Definition List](http://www.google.at/url?url=http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html%23h-10.3&rct=j&q=Description+lists+html&usg=AFQjCNEelUAV6ckdmHPGaz9n0mPeEV0o6g&sa=X&ei=bsxET_XOAoLOsgby193RDw&ved=0CCgQygQwAA) in a Lift Snippet like this:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Name</dt>
  <dd>Seppl</dd>

  <dt>Street</dt>
  <dd>abc</dd>
</dl>
```

The snippet-template looks now like this:

```
<dl>
  <div class="definition">
    <dt>Term</dt>
    <dd>Description</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

The Scala Snippet code:

```
def render = {
  val values=List(("Name", "Seppl"), ("Street", "abc"))

  ".definition" #> values.map(value => 
    ("dt" #> value._1) &
    ("dd" #> value._2))
}
```

This works, but I want a definition list without `div`-Tags (I think, this it isn't valid HTML.)

Is this possible with CSS Transformers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you don't seem to use CSS I would recommend you to use the following:

**Snippet Template code:**

```
<div class="lift:render"/>
```

**Scala Snippet code:**

```
def render = {
  val values=List(("Name", "Seppl"), ("Street", "abc"))

  values.map(value => 
    <dt>{value._1}</dt>
    <dd>{value._2}</dd>
  )
}
```

Of course I avoid using CSS selectors so I don't know if it is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, this works! (...but isn't very template-designer-friendly)

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Binding_via_CSS_Selectors

At the end of the page (Iteration) there's an example with unordered list.